# SQL query not functioning correctly, getting no output with a perfectly fine query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if ( isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['pass']) )
    {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '" . $_GET['user'] . "' AND `password` = '" . $_GET['pass'] . "';";
            echo("query: $sql <br />");
            $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "<password here>", "1596");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno($db)) { die("err"); }
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            echo($query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_aray($result);
            echo($row);
            if ($row['name'] == $_GET['user'])
            {
                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['name'];
                    $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
                    echo("logged in as " . $_SESSION['uid']);
            }
    }
    else
    {   
            die("Error, not enough parameters");
    }
?>
```

If I run that query on server, it is fine.. there is no connect error, so wondering where I went wrong

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you tried getting the value of your $sql variable and running that directly in SQL?

Comment: yes, [as I poorly worded in the question]. Works perfectly.

Comment: What does "run that query on server" mean? BTW you might want to familiarize yourself with the SQL injection.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: Don't quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: @AndyLester that does not solve the problem. The current setup is only a test, once it works I will change the input methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "<password here>", "1596");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($db)) { die("err"); }
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql); // line corrected
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // line corrected
```

Comment: Good fixes, though it does not solve the problem, I still get nothing from the rest of the script